# RStudio Shiny actionButton ignored

Tags: shiny, rstudio

Is the `input$goButton` in server.R that is triggered by `actionButton` supposed to be within an `if` statement in RStudio Shiny? The example on the Shiny webpage shows:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Click the button"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
                min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500),
    actionButton("goButton", "Go!")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("distPlot")
  )
))
```

and

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output, message) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # Take a dependency on input$goButton
    input$goButton

    # Use isolate() to avoid dependency on input$obs
    dist <- isolate(rnorm(input$obs))
    hist(dist, main=isolate(paste(system(paste("echo", dist[1],"> /tmp/1 && md5sum /tmp/1"),intern=TRUE),collapse='')))
  })
})
```

I have a slightly more complicated routine with more statements that the example above, and the event takes place event before the user clicks on the Go button. It makes me think `input$goButton` is ignored when one of the statements in the reactive is an R `system()` call.

```
Shiny Server v1.1.0.10000
Node.js v0.10.21
packageVersion: 0.10.0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Here it is shown that the dependency is ON the goButton as it is within the reactive expression. Look at this this way, if you want dependency on your button then simply type input$goButton in your reactive expression and everytime it is clicked the reactive expression will be executed.

Comment: In my rather more complicated example, I have a bunch of `isolate()` calls. Could that be the reason it is being triggered before the goButton? Can I have more than one `isolate()` inside the reactive call?

Comment: provide your example then I will be able to see what exact source of problem is

Comment: @pops I think I narrowed it down to `system()` commands being triggered regardless of the button. I updated my example.

Comment: So you want the to plot hist only upon pressing a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I this what you want? Whenever the button is pressed it will increase the count + 1 (starting with 0), hence there's and if statement with `return()` "nothing" if it hasn't been pressed

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
runApp(list(ui = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Click the button"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500),
    actionButton("goButton", "Go!")
  ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))),

  server = function(input, output,session) {
    my_data <- reactive({
      if(input$goButton == 0)
      {
        return()
      }
      isolate({
        input$goButton
        dist <- isolate(rnorm(input$obs))
        hist(dist, main=isolate(paste(system(paste("echo", dist[1],"> /tmp/1 && md5sum /tmp/1"),intern=TRUE),collapse=''))) 
      })
    })
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({my_data()
    })
  }
)
)
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly. I didn't imagine I would have to have `input$goButton` present twice, once in the if return() and the other inside a big isolate(). Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't be in the isolate() at all.  It's not doing anything.